# Find all finitely generated $\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Find all finitely generated $\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z$ modules.

To do this, let $M$ be a finitely generated $\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z$ module. Then $M$ is also $\Bbb Z$ module. Hence, we can write $M\simeq \Bbb Z^m\oplus\Bbb Z/p_1\Bbb Z\oplus\cdots\oplus\Bbb Z/p_n\Bbb Z$ where $m\geq 0$ and $p_1|p_2|\cdots|p_n$. Now, I quotient out this by $60\Bbb ZM$ so that it $\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z$ module structure, but I don't know how $\Bbb Z/p_i\Bbb Z$ part would be like. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to quotient out by $60\Bbb Z$, as $M$ is already a $\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z$-module, so $60M=\{0\}$.

In particular it implies that $m=0$ and each $p_i$ (which is by the way an unlucky notation) divides $60$.
And that's it.

Comment: Oh, so just view this $\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z$-module as $\Bbb Z$-module and that's it.
Can we always view $R/I$ module as $R$ module?

Comment: Yes, through the canonical homomorphism. If $M$ is an $R$-module then any ring homomorphism $f:S\to R$ induces an $S$-module structure on $M$ by simply $s\cdot m:=f(s)\cdot m$.